# Fetching Large Set of Mysql Data from Java

Tags: java

My project is in Spring Boot.
I need to fetch more than 150k of records in one go.
I am using Spring JPA.

However my result Query is giving GC overhead exception in server.
Surprisingly when I added a count(*) before fetching the actual records everything is running fine.

I am in search of a proper logical answer

Answer (score 0):

The query `count(*)` is very light weight query.
this will count the record and return the value only.
but `select` query fetches complete data, and here you are fetching 150000 records, which is very  very huge, so getting  **GC overhead exception** is obvious.

so,the solution is:
Either optimize your query, or use pagination  or use high end server.

Comment: Ok Thanks. Let me implement pagenation